# How to select a column WHERE its values are in json arrayin MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

In a word, I want to 
`select * from test.population where Number in (1,2,3)`,
but in the place of (1,2,3) I want to have a function that returns json array. So that I want to have this to be working like this.

```
select * from test.population where Number in ('[1,2,3]')
```

How to put json-array into where it clause?

Comment: sample data and expected result set would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MEMBER OF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) operator:

```
Number member of ('[1,2,3]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_SEARCH()`. It is available since MySQL 5.7, whereas `MEMBER OF()` came with MySQL 8.0:

```
select * from test.population where json_search('[1,2,3]', 'one', number) is not null
```